# Use Vue.js in Laravel to refresh table data from API request every 5 seconds

Tags: laravel, rest, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I am trying to refresh a page every 5 seconds with Vue.js that holds a table with data coming from an API request in Laravel. This data is created with a controller:

```
 $response = $wowzaSME->request("GET", "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/".$gemeente->name."/pushpublish/mapentries/".$gemeente->name);
        $decoded = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

So how can I retrieve this API request with Vue.js every 5 seconds from this controller in my blade view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` to create a recurring API call.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
setInterval(() => { this.fetchApiData() }, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work in Laravel plus it's not Vue.js

Comment: You want a page (client) to refresh some table data every 5 seconds via an api request to Laravel (server). Am I correct so far? Therefore your client must execute some JavaScript (see my answer again) making the same api request. So 1) JavaScript does not run through a php interpreter (Laravel) and 2) vue.js is a framework, not a programming language. And surprise! Vue.js is in fact written in JavaScript (again, see my answer). Therefore, you should reread my answer.

Comment: Will have a closer look at it.